# How does cls work under the hood? (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

Basically the windows analog for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124762/how-does-clear-command-work), which answers it for unix/linux.

Comment: somehow I doubt that you are going to find answers comparable to the linux answers, as windows shells need not be simple character devices because they aren't attempting to support IBM terminal protocols from the mid-70's (eg VT-100, etc).

Comment: I'm wondering if powershell uses the same thing as the one provided by cmd.exe? If not, at least I'll know the source for `cls` in powershell

Comment: Ok, it's an alias to [Clear-Host](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/1825b6021754b00b6bcb7ea0a8f9d80913d80583/docs/learning-powershell/powershell-beginners-guide.md#L82)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26175996/2861476) could help you.

Answer (score 3):

Native Windows programs use the [Console API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console) to interact with console windows (although it *is* also slowly getting ANSI/xterm terminal protocol support in Windows 10).

There is Microsoft documentation page [Clearing the Screen](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/console/clearing-the-screen) which describes how to clear a console:

1. Use [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) to get buffer information;
2. Use [FillConsoleOutputCharacter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputcharacter) to fill the buffer with spaces;
3. Use [FillConsoleOutputAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputattribute) to reset the colors;
4. Use [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) to move the cursor to (0, 0).